# ContextMenuService in Windows Phone 8, still use Toolkit?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-8

I want to apply a ContextMenu in my LongListSelector in my WP8 app. However I cannot find the ContextMenu that were in the WP7 toolkit. Do I still have to use that one (I rather not)?

If that's true how do I get around that both the toolkit and the phone have a LongListSelector. Because when I'm trying to build my project the compiler whines about there are two LongListSelectors and the build fails.

> Error 2   The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' exists in both 'x:\Dropbox\Dropbox\X\packages\SilverlightToolkitWP.4.2012.10.9\lib\sl3-wp\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll'    X:\Dropbox\Dropbox\X\X\obj\Debug\Views\MainPage.g.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I cannot find the ContextMenu that were in the WP7 toolkit. Do I still have to use that one (I rather not)?

Yes.

> If that's true how do I get around that both the toolkit and the phone have a LongListSelector.

Update your version of the Toolkit to the WP8 version, from http://phone.codeplex.com/